# Slideshow of Image Folder whose files increase

Tags: bash, webcam, streaming, avconv, imagemagick

I am trying to stream video from my webcam to a series of images, process these images through a bash script that uses convert (`imagemagick`) and then output them to a folder.

I have been successful with the above, but am having trouble creating a slideshow (or streaming video) that takes those output images and streams them real time.

I have tried several slide show programs... `display`, `fbi`, `feh`, `animate`, `gthumb`. They all work great in making a slideshow. However, because this is a live stream from a webcam, the number of images keeps increasing. When the slideshow program is run, it only reads as many images that have been created up to the point of program run.

I have attached an image that diagrams what I am trying to do.

Any suggestions?

[image: diagram of process]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use [Eye of Gnome](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/EyeOfGnome) (Ubuntu package name: `eog`). I just tested Eye of Gnome version 3.10.2 under Ubuntu 14.04, and confirmed that it does successfully detect new images in a directory and incorporate them into a running slideshow.

Here's the bash script I used to test the functionality (requires ImageMagick):

```
#!/bin/bash

TEMPDIR=$(mktemp -d)

function deletetempdir {
  rm -rf "$TEMPDIR"
}

# Automatically remove slideshow directory on exit
trap deletetempdir EXIT

function makeimage {
  convert -size 500x100 xc:white -pointsize 72 \
          -draw "text 5,60 '$1'" $TEMPDIR/$2.png
}

makeimage One 1
makeimage Two 2

eog -s $TEMPDIR & # start EOG in slideshow mode

sleep 30

makeimage 'New image!' 3

sleep 30

kill $! # kill EOG
```

EOG will cycle between the two initial images for 30 seconds; at this point, the script creates a new image, which EOG adds automatically to the end of the slideshow.